# Integrating EJB and OSGI using Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle

I want to integrate some EJB modules with OSGI framework using Eclipse.

How can I do this?

Comment: So you have EJBs on the server side and an Eclipse RCP application on the client side? Or do you simply want to write the client using OSGi and Eclipse? Can you also write what EJB server you use?

Comment: I have EJBs on the server side and my client using OSGI and Eclipse should access that service. I am using JBoss7.1.1

Comment: On the client side: Do you mean that you build a Eclipse RCP application?

Comment: yes.. I want to create a Eclipse RCP application

Comment: @user1586908 All the information you have provided in the comments should have been already in the question, because without them it is impossible to answer the question (and you'll get downvotes for the question). But there is hope: you can fix this by editing the question!

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions to this:

1. Install the EJB client jars as bundles and use them from OSGi to access the EJBs.
   If the client jars are not yet bundles you can use the maven bundle plugin to create bundles for them.
2. Publish the EJBs as webservices on the server side and use JAXWS/JAXB on the client side to access the services